# Switching between images and changing div size in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div that needs to switch between background images as well as size.  I'm able to get the initial(first) click to change the background image and div size correctly, but when I click on it again, I'm unable to return it to it's original size and background image.  Can anyone explain to me what I need to do?

**CSS**

```
#navigation{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/left.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#navigation").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).css("background-image", "url(images/left.png)")){
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/right.png)");
        $(this).animate({width: 100}, 350);
    }
    else{
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/left.png)");
        $(this).animate({width: 25}, 350);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#navigation").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).css("background-image") == "url(images/left.png)"){
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/right.png)");
        $(this).animate({width: 100}, 350);
    }else{
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/left.png)");
        $(this).animate({width: 25}, 350);
    }
});
```

But better try adding a class

```
  $("#navigation").on("click", function(){
        var ths = $(this);
        if(ths.hasClass('bg-image-left')){
            ths.css("background-image", "url(images/right.png)")
               .animate({width: 100}, 350)
               .removeClass('bg-image-left');
        } else {
            ths.css("background-image", "url(images/left.png)");
               .animate({width: 25}, 350);
               .addClass('bg-image-left');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The best things is to use addClass and removeClass. You need to created two

I have used a background color instead to make it testable.

different CSS classes  see  the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alanmehio/73bzveoh/4/)